# plot irregular data with matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, scipy, triangulation, convex-hull, linear-interpolation

I have function data within a `LinearNDInterpolator` that I can evaluate using a meshgrid, and it looks pretty decent aside from some rendering glitches unique to the input data.

```py
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = interp(X, Y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap="viridis")
```

To work around the glitches I need to render the surface at a resolution that exceeds my resources. Also, the glitches are ameliorated when using triangular meshes. So I was hoping to plot the sparse data contained within the convex-hull without interpolating to a regular grid, which would waste memory. Unfortunately the resulting surface is a jumble of skinny triangles; a forest of broken glass. I was under the impression that `LinearNDInterpolator` simply interpolated the triangles without changing the mesh, so I'm wondering why the result is so poor.

```py
qhull = interp.tri
mptri = mpl.tri.Triangulation\
    ( x = qhull.points[:, 0]
    , y = qhull.points[:, 1]
    , triangles = qhull.vertices
    )
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")
ax.plot_trisurf(mptri, interp.values, cmap="viridis")
```

Comment: This question would benefit from example data and plots.

Comment: I was able to build a build a Delaunay triangulation from a regular grid using `LinearNDInterpolator` and plot the trisurf successfully. I think I'm having an issue with the qhull generated by the `adaptive` library. I'll close this and open an issue with them.